# Modeling a Simple Class Hierarchy, C#

Tags: c#

I have 6 concepts that need to be modelled:

Vehicle
Car
Truck
Road
Drive
Boat

The obvious ones are Vehicle<-Car,Truck,Boat - and I'm thinking that Drive could be an abstract method on Vehicle, but it's the Road concept that is giving me trouble as to the most logical way to incorporate.

Any suggestions/advice are appreciated.

Comment: Your would probably want to pass a Road to the Drive() method.  Road should probably also be an abstract class, which you could subclass to GravelRoad, ResidentialStreet, MajorStreet, Freeway or similar.

Comment: @David - unless you wanted to Drive your Boat.

Comment: Well a Road has Cars on it, and Cars can Drive. Honestly, the model is a little unclear here, because depending on what you're modeling exactly, I could see a case for either A)a Road implemented as a collection of cars (that are currently on it), or B)a Car has a Road member/field that represents the current road it's on. It really depends on more specifics of the model, which you haven't given. Tell your prof A&B, give an explanation for both cases, and I'm certain it'll earn you a good mark. Good luck!

Comment: @Graphain -- good point :)  But if this is homework maybe the instructor is trying to make the point that real-world abstractions don't always translate cleanly into software.

Comment: Maybe Road needs to be a subclass of Thoroughfare, the other obvious subclass being Waterway?

Answer (score 1):

I don't want to give too much away, as this sounds like homework.

However, the concept you are looking for is the *Interface*

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87d83y5b%28v=vs.80%29.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx

Interfaces, allow you to have objects that are not directly related (i.e. don't necessarily have a common class they descend from apart from `Object`) to both implement the same method. They thus allow you to treat two different things (`Person` and `Car` say) by their behaviour (e.g. both might implement an `IMove` interface, defining a `Move` method).

---

Having said that, you could probably get away without Interfaces here, by considering which of those items use the `Road`, and which do not. I think there's room for a common ancestor of these "Road Using" classes, that also descends from `Vehicle`.